# Facing an issue when writing tests for windows driver using Appium test framework

Tags: xamarin, uwp, appium, xamarin.uwp, appium-desktop

I am trying to automate a windows app using the Appium test framework. So I referred the below link [Appium test framework](http://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/windows/)

I followed all the steps mentioned in the above link but I am getting an error in the below line

```
DesktopSession = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri(WindowsApplicationDriverUrl),appCapabilities);
```

[image]

Can anyone please give a possible solution to resolve the above issue.

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images

Answer (score 0):

Eswaran Thirugnanasambandam

This issue not reproduced in Appium.WebDriver - 3.0.0.1 version. I think you are using higher version. Please check and downgrade the nuget and test the app